# how to download (dynamically) a file from a particular link using C#

Tags: c#

I know By using `WebClient` class we can download the files directly.
By using this code `web.DownloadFile("url", "filename");`

But in my scenario I should call this(https://www.nseindia.com/reports/gsm) link and when this link triggered the "Download (.csv)" link should download automatically (you can see this download option in image and highlighted with blue color circle)

Note :

if I click on this download link it starting the downloading in the same link and will not not giving the download link separately. So I should call this download link through the coding only.

So how can we achieve this type of file downloading's.

Give me your best suggestions to achieve this.

[image: This is example of download file]

Comment: Unclear question! would you please explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: sure @Transcendent , if I call this link "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/gsm". I should download the "download(.csv)" file (highlighted in blue circle) . So how to achieve this ?

Comment: I now understand what you mean. The target website uses JavaScript to trigger the link. This means that you cannot simply read the web page, parse the HTML, and extract the link, and instead you need to do something more advanced. Take a look at `Selenium` and it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: It would Unethical if I provided you with the exact solution, because the developers of the target website have designed this procedure deliberately in such a way that one could not write a bot to download links. For that reason, I will vote for close and will leave it up to you to find the exact solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is not ethical to answer this question. This is because, the OP is asking us to solve a problem that has been designed deliberately to offload traffic as a result of automation. This would be equal to writing an exploit.

Comment: @Transcendent I do not necessarily with your assessment. After a brief look at the website, in this particular case, it looks to me like this was most likely just the simplest way for the web developer to implement that CSV download. In fact, [this API URL](https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportGSM) is not even protected by a cookie, and will likely be easier to parse either way.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to solving problems like this:

- Open the network tab on your browser devtools
- download the object you want to fetch with your program, and
- look for the object's download.
- Inspect that object in the network tab to determine its Url.
- Then try that URL in your (C#) program.

If you get the object, fine. If you don't, the web site owner may have built anti-scraping protection for the object. For example, you may need to be logged in to the site to access the object.